# Difference between Forward Merge and Backward Merge

Tags: svn

What's the simplest way to describe a  "Forward Merge" vs. a "Backward Merge" when using SVN?

Comment: In what context are you using "forward merge"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by *forward merge* and *backwards* merge? I can think of two separate possible meanings:

1. I merged a change (or did a change) into a branch or the trunk, and now I want to undo that change.
2. I merged my trunk into a branch (forward merge?), and now I want to merge my branch back into my trunk (backwards merge?).

In the first context:

I did a change in my repository back in revision 12345. This change isn't working out, and now I want to *undo* that change:

```
$ svn merge -c -12345 .
```

This is a reverse merge where I am removing a particular change from Subversion. This is equivalent to the command:

```
$ svn merge -r12345:12344 .
```

---

In the second context:

When you merge, you usually do what is known as a *three-way* merge. I created a branch to implement some feature. I want to keep the changes on my trunk in my branch as I do my work:

```
$ svn checkout $REPO/branches/mybranch .
$ svn merge $REPO/trunk
```

This does a *three-way* merge and could be thought of as a *forward merge*. I want my changes on trunk to be placed on my branch, but I don't want to wipe out the changes I made on my branch itself. In order to do this, Subversion compares the branch to the trunk **and** to the last common ancestor between the branch and the trunk.

Imagine my file before the branch looked like this:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

The file on my branch now looks like this:

```
one
foo
foo
four
five
six
```

and the file on my trunk now looks like this:

```
one
two
bar
four
bar
bar
```

By comparing the pre-branched version of the file, Subversion can see that I changed lines two, and three on my branch. By comparing the pre-branched version with my trunk, Subversion can see I changed lines three, five, and six on my trunk.

Subversion will merge only lines five and six from my trunk to my branch. Subversion knows that line two was changed on my branch only and should not be touched. However, Subversion can see that line three was changed on both my branch and on trunk. Therefore, it will say there's a *merge conflict* and ask me if I want the trunk version of line #3 or the branch version of line #3.

Subversion is really a bit tricker than this. It doesn't merely compare the head of the branch and trunk with the last common ancestor, it compares the *individual revision changes* on the trunk since the branch happened. Subversion does this to prevent me from merging in changes a second time. It does this by using the property `svn:mergeinfo`.

Now if you have been merging from the trunk to the branch (forward merge?) all this time, your branch contains all of the changes that took place on trunk. When I finally want to merge my feature branch back into my trunk (backwards merge?), doing a three way merge is pretty useless. I would be comparing the merged trunk information on my branch against the trunk itself.

Subversion handles this by doing a *two-way* merge instead of a normal *three way* merge. This is called *reintegration*. In this case, Subversion compares only my branch to my trunk, and tries to make my trunk look like just like my branch.

There are implementation issues with this because of the way Subversion tracks merging which is why you need to be very careful about reusing a branch once you do this *reintegration merge*. It is usually recommended to lock or delete the branch, and if you do need the branch again, to recreate it from scratch. There's another method using the `--record-only` parameter of the merge command to allow you to reuse the branch.

---

So, in one context, the *backwards* merge refers to undoing a change which means that the normal change could be thought of as a *forward merge*.

In the other context, the merging of changes done on one branch or on the trunk to another branch is considered the forward direction, and the *backwards merge* is when you go the other direction.

So, which context are you talking about when you ask about *forward* and *backwards* merging?

Answer (score 1):

We used to use that language at the Siemens Healthcare Ultrasound unit where everything was under the Rational ClearCase SCM tool, which I'm hoping relates closely enough to SVN. There was so many developers, all around the globe and in different time zones, that the way things were done was that everyone had their own user branch. This branch would originate off the trunk at some revision and where the user would introduce all their local changes within their working copy and make any user level checkins if necessary. Once that developer finished their work and were ready to push those changes back into the trunk they would first do a "***back merge***" which merged the current state of the trunk into their working copy to make sure that they resolved any conflicts, grabbed new changes, and what not. Once all was tidied up and there were no further checkins they would then do a ***forward merge*** to push their changes back into the trunk. So essentially in that lingo backmerges were basically synching up with the current state of the trunk into your working copy and forwardmerges were pushing your working copies up into the trunk.

In reality this would occur no matter what relative position the "trunk" was at, whether it was the true main trunk, or any sub branches that carried a special release or set of features and what not. I tried to find an image of a Clearcase Version Tree Browser GUI screenshot that demonstrated a forward and backward merge both occurring in one user branch but all I could find was this image which shows the forward merge taking place in one part, and a backward merge taking place in another. But imagine the same with the arrows going to and from along two branches each progressing in their development independently of each other. FYI versions stack vertically along these branches in Clearcase with old on top and new on bottom so that the time axis points downwards.

** UPDATE **
Looks like this feature was added to SVN under the title of **Revision Graphs**. Check out this [writeup](http://www.syntevo.com/blog/?p=3485) on it.

> Displaying "merge arrows" in the Revision Graph is a feature which has
>   been requested rather frequently since Subversion has introduced
>   "merge tracking". This request comes mainly from (former) ClearCase
>   users.

[image: Rational Clearcase Version Tree Browser with both merge types displayed]

Answer (score 0):

A "reverse merge" is undoing changes in the repository, while keeping a record of both the original change and the undoing of that change.

I'll edit in "forward merge" when you've clarified.